# Why can't i get the text value using request.form in flask to perform sentimental analysis on the text?

Tags: python, html, flask, sentiment-analysis

I am quite inexperienced in both HTML, JS and flask but I am working on a chatbot that able to detect sentimental analysis of the sender.

My HTML code:

```
      <div class="bottom_wrapper clearfix">
        <div class="message_input_wrapper">
          <form action = "{{ url_for('reply') }}" method = "POST">
          <input
            class="message_input"
            id="text_message"
            name = "sentimental_name"
            placeholder="Tell me how you feel today..."
            onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13)document.getElementById('send').click()">  
        </div>


        <!--div class = "send_message1" id = 'audio' onclick = "start_dictation()">


        <span style="font-size: 32px; color:black;">
          <i class="fas fa-microphone"></i>
        </span>
      </div-->
        <div class="send_message" id="send" onclick="get_message()">
          <!--<div class="icon"></div>-->

          <div class="text">Send</div>

        </div>
      </form>
      </div>
```

This is my python-flask code:

```
@app.route('/senti', methods = ['POST'])
def reply():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        message = request.form['text_message']
        a = TextBlob(message).sentiment.polarity
        b = TextBlob(message).sentiment.subjectivity
```

My js that links to the onlick =

```
function get_message(){
var message = document.getElementById("text_message").value;
var json_data = {"msg":message}
var sender = JSON.stringify(json_data)
console.log(sender)
console.log(message);
insert_chat('me',message);
interact(sender);
 }
```

Console log:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/senti 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)
send    @   jquery-3.4.1.js:9837
ajax    @   jquery-3.4.1.js:9434
interact    @   chat.js:34
get_message @   chat.js:55
onclick @   chat:58
```

It seems really simple but it is like I miss something. Thank you so much!

Comment: you have to use `"sentimental_name"` in `request.form["sentimental_name"]` because you have `<input  name="sentimental_name" ...>`

Comment: @furas I did that already. The output still said "The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."

Comment: I see some JavaScript function which probably is executed when you click `send` `<div class="send_message" id="send" onclick="get_message()">` Maybe this function changes data and make mess. Show this function in question.  Did you run in debug mode to see more information in browser ? Add these information in question. Did you run in console to see error messages in console? Show these messages in question.

Comment: @furas you are right. The problem is in the js get_message(). This is my first time dealing with js so I am not sure how the js change the value to the point there is no name == 'sentimental_name'. Thank you so so much!! I learn a lot!

Comment: it seems it convert it to JSON with `"msg"`. It can be send as `data`, not `form`. Maybe in flask check `print(requests.data)`, `print(request.form)`.

Comment: you can also use `requests.data.get("msg")` and `request.form.get("msg")`instead of `["msg"]` becauses `get()` returns `None` when it can't find `"msg"` and you can use `if not message:` to catch this problem. And `["msg"]` raise error when there is no `"msg"` and you would have to use `try:/except:` to catch it.

Comment: and JavaScript may expect that `reply()` returns also JSON - ie. `return jsonify(list_or_dictionary)`. In JavaScript I see `interact(sender);` so you would have to find this function and see what it sends and what result it may expect.

Comment: @furas I think I figure out the problem! wow. I am really glad you decided to answer. Is there anyway I can give you the check thingy for your helpfulness?

Comment: I put comments as answer and you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use `"sentimental_name"` in

```
request.form["sentimental_name"]
```

because you have

But it uses JavaScript function `get_message()` to get data when you click `ENTER`

```
<input ... onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13)document.getElementById('send').click()"> 

<div class="send_message" id="send" onclick="get_message()">
```

and converts to JSON with field `"msg"` so it sends it as `data` or `json`, not `form`.

```
function get_message(){
   var message = document.getElementById("text_message").value;
   var json_data = {"msg":message}
   var sender = JSON.stringify(json_data)
   console.log(sender)
   console.log(message);
   insert_chat('me',message);
   interact(sender);
```

In flask `reply()` you can check this using:

```
print(request.args)
print(request.data)
print(request.form)
print(request.json)
```

JavaScript may expect that `reply()` returns also `JSON` - ie.

```
return jsonify(list_or_dictionary).
```

In JavaScript I see `interact(sender);` so you would have to find this function and see what it sends and what result it may expect.

---

BTW: you can also use `requests.data.get("msg")` and `request.form.get("msg")` instead of `["msg"]` becauses `.get()` returns `None` when it can't find `"msg"` and you can use `if not message:` to catch this problem. And `["msg"]` raises error when there is no `"msg"` and you would have to use `try:/except:` to catch it.